# creating an pod_tuple-class which is standard layout and trivially copyable with some type-modifications

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I am trying to write a pod_tuple-class which is trivially copyable and standard layout (of course only if that also counts for the types itself). it should feel the same like std::tuple but does only need to be created and have an index-sequenced pack-expansion similar to use std::get.
That is needed since we have an architecture, where a user can call a callee with a Parameter Pack but he does not need to know what it's actually calling. We have a multi-core-architecture (with same Arm-architecture and compiler for each core) with an IPC available. That means there is an soleley-running compiled instance on each core.

I managed with some help of some articles and also ChatGPT to write a class which can work as an pod_tuple.

There are some points to clarify and I will start with the draft I got:

**1. recursion does not end correctly**

```cpp
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdio>

template<typename... Ts>
struct pod_tuple;

template<>
struct pod_tuple<> {
    // empty tuple
};

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct pod_tuple<T, Ts...> : pod_tuple<Ts...> {
    // tuple with at least one element
    typedef typename std::remove_reference_t <T> TNoRef;
    TNoRef value;
//    static_assert(std::is_trivially_copyable<TNoRef>::value, "pack types must be trivially copyable");
//    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout<TNoRef>::value, "pack types must be standard layout");

    // default constructor
    pod_tuple() = default;

    // constructor from values
    pod_tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : pod_tuple<Ts...>(ts...), value(t) {}

    // copy constructor
    pod_tuple(const pod_tuple& other) = default;

    // copy assignment operator
    pod_tuple& operator=(const pod_tuple& other) = default;

    // destructor
    ~pod_tuple() = default;
};

//// helper function to get the element of a tuple by index
template<std::size_t I, typename T>
struct tuple_element;

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_element<0, pod_tuple<T, Ts...>> {
    using type = T;
};

template<std::size_t I, typename T, typename... Ts>
struct tuple_element<I, pod_tuple<T, Ts...>> {
    using type = typename tuple_element<I-1, pod_tuple<Ts...>>::type;
};

template<std::size_t I, typename T>
using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element<I, T>::type;

template<std::size_t I, typename T, typename... Ts>
tuple_element_t<I, pod_tuple<T, Ts...>>& get(pod_tuple<T, Ts...>& t) {
    return get<I-1>(static_cast<pod_tuple<Ts...>&>(t));
}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
T& get(pod_tuple<T, Ts...>& t) {
    return t.value;
}
```

Using it:

```cpp
template<typename... TParams>
void call(TParams... args)
{
    printf("Iamcalled!");
}

template <std::size_t... Is, typename... TParams>
void callWithTuple(pod_tuple<TParams...>& tuple, std::index_sequence<Is...> /* dummy */)
{
    call(get<Is>(tuple)...);
}

int main()
{
    pod_tuple<int, char> myTuple(3,'s');

    callWithTuple(myTuple, std::index_sequence_for<int, char>());
}
```

and I get errors which are based on the `I-1` where `I` reaches `0` and the end of the recursion which I would've seen in  `tuple_element<0, pod_tuple<T, Ts...>>` is not reached. Instead it substracts 1 from 0 when following the get-recursion:

```
<source>: In instantiation of 'struct tuple_element<18446744073709551615, pod_tuple<char> >':
<source>:54:7:   required by substitution of 'template<long unsigned int I, class T> using tuple_element_t = typename tuple_element::type [with long unsigned int I = 18446744073709551615; T = pod_tuple<char>]'
<source>:57:42:   required by substitution of 'template<long unsigned int I, class T, class ... Ts> tuple_element_t<I, pod_tuple<T, Ts ...> >& get(pod_tuple<T, Ts ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 18446744073709551615; T = char; Ts = {}]'
<source>:58:20:   required from 'tuple_element_t<I, pod_tuple<T, Ts ...> >& get(pod_tuple<T, Ts ...>&) [with long unsigned int I = 0; T = int; Ts = {char}; tuple_element_t<I, pod_tuple<T, Ts ...> > = int]'
<source>:75:17:   required from 'void callWithTuple(pod_tuple<Ts ...>&, std::index_sequence<Is ...>) [with long unsigned int ...Is = {0, 1}; TParams = {int, char}; std::index_sequence<Is ...> = std::integer_sequence<long unsigned int, 0, 1>]'
<source>:82:18:   required from here
<source>:50:11: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct tuple_element<18446744073709551614, pod_tuple<> >'
   50 |     using type = typename tuple_element<I-1, pod_tuple<Ts...>>::type;
```

Example is here: https://godbolt.org/z/PGxMh9bbe

I am not that deep into template-meta-programming but I can't see why the end of the recursion is not reached.

**2. removing and readding references**

My further thought was that once the `pod_tuple`-recursion works I want to automatically remove and later add references again.
In the example code of 1. you can find:

```cpp
    typedef typename std::remove_reference_t <T> TNoRef;
    TNoRef value;
```

which I added there. So far so good, that removes the references. Remembering our use-case (transferring the `pod_tuple` via IPC to another core) we know that the other cores have an exact same matching template declaration which ensures the `pod_tuple` Parameter pack-types are defined exactly like on the sending core (same compiler and code-base for both cores). So the receiving core-code knows whether there are references or not.
If I now want to call `callWithTuple` with the `pod_tuple` (on the receiving core) which uses the referenced types this won't work that way I guess? I think I need to additionally define a `make_tuple`-like function which first removes the references and on the receiving core another `make_tuple` which adds the references? Or is the type-definition with reference enough? I think not since the `callWithTuple` will insert the sequence-elements directly by the type it knows from the template Parameter pack and not from the pod_tuple which has removed references. So how can I add them again?

**3. calling a function of a pod_tuple-passed type automatically**

We are also using etl (embedded template library).
They provide a string-class (https://www.etlcpp.com/string.html) which is used by us. This string class is copyable via memcpy (but `std::is_trivially_copyable` fails!). But afterwards you need to call a `repair()` function. Since I want to hide the implementation to the user he shall not be informed if the call came from the own core or from another core. So he will not know if he has to call `repair()` or not. This is also available for some other etl-containers.
I saw this post:
[How can you check whether a templated class has a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/how-can-you-check-whether-a-templated-class-has-a-member-function)
And came up with a modification for C++14 (second answer in link):

```cpp
namespace detail{
template<class>
struct sfinae_true : std::true_type{};
  template<class T>
  static auto test_repair(int)
      -> sfinae_true<decltype(std::declval<T>().repair())>;
  template<class>
  static auto test_repair(long) -> std::false_type;
} // detail::

template<class T>
struct has_repair : decltype(detail::test_repair<T>(0)){};
```

Unfortunately because of the previous compilation errors I did not come further to test it. But my thought is to use this like the index-sequence, while iterating over all types in the tuple when receiving (maybe even in the `callWithTuple`-function) and calling the function `repair()` (like `T::repair()`) in case of a match.
But that sounds a bit to easy. Is it possible to use `std::enable_if` to achieve such a goal at compile-time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"it should feel the same like std::tuple"_ - Why was `std::tuple` disqualified from being used?

Comment: @TedLyngmo because ```std::tuple``` is not trivially copyable (and provides no repair()-like function) and is not standard-layout. The data needs to be transmitted via a raw storing in RAM. That also between cores which share RAM and can access the same memory regions. All I read about std::tuple (here on SO) is that you should not use it if you need to store parameter packed data into memory.
We are currently using it btw with that risk. At least we ensure that it is not called with any non trivially copyable and not standard layout types in the current setup.

Comment: Ah, yes, I see.

Comment: As an initial matter, `pod_type` is not standard-layout. One of the requirements for the standard-layout class is that "only one class in the hierarchy has non-static data members".

Comment: @IgorTandetnik oh. I just added a static_assert and you are right. Damn. Then I need to rethink this.

Comment: There's an easy way to write `tuple_element`. Like this: `template<std::size_t I, typename... Ts> struct tuple_element<I, pod_tuple<Ts...>> { using type = std::tuple_element_t<I, std::tuple<Ts...>>; };` Reduce the problem to one already solved.